# Extract road edges from point cloud pcl ros melodic

Tags: ros, ransac, pcl

I am trying to extract features (vertices and road edges) from ground plane point cloud.
I have the ground plane estimated from RANSAC
The point cloud is from  road and off-road points of a street.
I need to detect the road. So I need the edges of a road.
This is what I am referring to as "edges"

Can someone please suggest a way to extract this information from point cloud?

Comment: More information is needed to answer this question. What have you tried so far that doesn't work? You cannot reliably detect valid road lines simply from a point cloud. At the very least you'll need to incorporate ocular data.

Comment: I am trying to localize a robot.
I have an open street map from which I only have very basic data like road edges and vertices.

I was able to get the road edges and vertices from open street map.
Now for correction part I have a lidar data point cloud.
I extracted the ground plane from the point cloud and now I have to detect road edges and vertices from lidar data 
And try to match it with the prior open street map data

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not something you can do with only lidar. This is really a job for an ocular setup.